# How can I get RandomNumber by using Chainlink VRF

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

this is RandomNumberConsumer.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {
    event RequestFulfilled(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness);

    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    uint256 public randomResult;

    constructor()
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0x7a1BaC17Ccc5b313516C5E16fb24f7659aA5ebed, // VRF Coordinator
            0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB // LINK Token
        )
    {
        keyHash = 0x4b09e658ed251bcafeebbc69400383d49f344ace09b9576fe248bb02c003fe9f;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK (Varies by network)
    }

    /**
     * Requests randomness
     */
    function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(
            LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee,
            "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet"
        );
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
     */
    function fulfillRandomness(
        bytes32 requestId,
        uint256 randomness
    ) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness;
        emit RequestFulfilled(requestId, randomness);
    }

}
```

I deployed and verified my contract in mumbai testnet.
And I send link token to deployed contract.
But error occurs When I call getRandomNumber.
"We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail"
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using VRF version 1, which is deprecated. You should switch to VRF version 2 by checking [this guide](https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2/subscription/examples/get-a-random-number) from the Chainlink official docs.